# Is this code too naive?

Tags: javascript, function

I tried running the following function using the JS code below. I am a JS beginner, I have no idea why it is not working.

f(x)={x+1 if x<2; -2x+7 if x>=2;}

```
function f(x) {
    if (x<2) {
        return x+1;
    }
    else if (x>=2) {
        return -2x+7;
    }
}
```

Comment: Naivety is largely a matter of opinion, which is off-topic for Stackoverflow.  Your question lacks a clear problem statement — what does "not working" mean? What should it do? What does it do? What errors does the console report? — so it is off-topic. Your question is badly formatted, use the editing tools for format you code so it is readable. Click the button that lets you write a live demon in the question.

Comment: It's not valid JS. If you want multiplication, you need to be explicit.  Change this line: return -2x+7; to this: return (-2 * x)+7;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a multiplication operator.

```
return -2 * x + 7;
//        ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't have *implicit multiplication*, meaning that `2x` is not syntactically valid.

I also don't like the way you're so explicit with your `else` condition: that can lead to program control falling into unexpected places<sup>1</sup>. That is, remove `if (x>=2)` completely.

In fact, why not write

```
return x < 2 ? x + 1 : -2 * x + 7;
```

instead?

---

<sup>1</sup>`x` might be a floating point `NaN` in that case *neither* case is true, and the return value of your function is not explicit.

Comment: `x < 2 ? x + 1 : -2 * x + 7` probably looks like gibberish to someone who doesn't know they have to write `2*x` :) Ternary operators are on day 2

Comment: @JeremyThille: Sadly that's the curse of my once being a geeky childhood programmer and think this stuff is obvious to everyone. You make a very good point.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because a ternary is obviously more elegant that a redundant `if...else`, but nonetheless, I think OP would read more easily `return (x<2) ? (x+1) : (-2*x+7)`

Comment: @JeremyThille: Personally I think excess parentheses are from the devil. Learn that precedence table; really it doesn't take long. I allow them for nested ternary conditionals though in PHP since those wisecracks in an act of sheer devilry reversed the associativity!

Comment: Actually I managed to decipher it. A quick google search is all it takes.

Comment: @Bathsheba I know, I know. But we're not into super-advanced-optimized code here, we're educating a newbie...

Comment: @JeremyThille: I'm not sure it's advanced. In respect that the ternary conditional operator was invented before the `if` `else` block, it could be held up to be anachronistic!

Comment: `I think excess parentheses are from the devil`, easy to read code is from heaven.  Bit like putting a space after a comma in parameters, much nicer.

Comment: I find code littered with excess parentheses to be from the devil. Where do you stop? You end up with stuff like `if ((x == y) == true)` written by quiche eaters.

Comment: `Where do you stop?`,, if it makes code easier to read, you don't.  Also it has little or no effect on performance.

Comment: @Keith We will have to agree to disagree. I find code with excess parentheses difficult to read. The C like grammars are very expressive; learn it thoroughly and roll with it.

Comment: `We will have to agree to disagree.`,  Of course..  I just come from a place were sometimes people have to read my code too.  `learn it thoroughly and roll with it.`, I have no problem understanding it, I came from C myself.

Comment: @Keith: You're hired!

Comment: hehe, hope you don't want me to doing C coding,..  The days of `while(*t++=*s++);` are hopefully long gone.. :)

Answer (score 2):

your were missing a multiplication operator `*` in `-2x+7`. it would be `-2*x+7` like below

```js
function f(x) {
if (x<2) {
    return x+1;
}
else if (x>=2) {
    return -2*x+7;
}
}

console.log(f(3));  // returns 1 
console.log(f(1));  // returns 2
```